# Batch update in php

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a mysql table with multiple fields:

```
 SNo id status
```

Now the status has changed and i need to update it when the value of Sno is 1 from my php script. I do not want to do it individually as this may be time consuming. Is there any way to update the values of status when I have the value of Sno which it corresponds to other than deleting these columns and doing an insert again.

The value of new status is not a constant. Lets assume that there are 4 entries with sno 1 and the status field is originally all false. Now lets say I want to update it and have a string true,true,false,false. I want the staus to be updated to true,true,flase,false exactly in the order that they appear in the table.

Comment: Review the [MySQL UPDATE syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html).. Something like `UPDATE yourtable SET status = 'newstatus' WHERE SNo = 'value for SNo'`

Comment: Edited the question.PLease take a look

Answer (score 2):

Not completely sure what you mean, but I think you are looking for:

```
UPDATE `table` SET `status` = 'new status' WHERE `SNo` = '1'
```

Comment: yep, thats how i understood the question.

Comment: My bad. Guess I was not clear enough. The value of new status is not a constant. Lets assume that there are 4 entries with sno 1 and the status filed is originally all false. Now lets say I want to update it and have a string `true,true,false,false`. I want the staus to be updated to true,true,flase,false exactly in the order that they appear in the table.

Comment: Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: @Developer Android In that case you would have to update them individually.

Comment: Okay. Let me try that out then.

Comment: @DeveloperAndroid You could always use a prepared statement or a transaction if your db allows it.